# How to separate jQuery from HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I've tried all the combinations I could think about and didn't figure it out. Here's my working code (all in the HTML document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $alert = $('.alert');
        if ($alert.length) {
            var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                $alert.trigger('click');
            }, 3000);
            $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function () {
                window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here's the call:

```
<div id="alert"><a href="../Home/English">English</a></div>
```

Now I want to refactor so the script goes in a .js file. How would it look like once refactored? Thanks!

Comment: It would look the same except that your script block would be an external js file ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what have you tried so far?

Comment: One error I noticed $('.alert') looks for an element with the alert class. You probably want to change the js to say
var $alert=$('#alert');

Comment: @Jasper: That would be long to list. Tried to change the HTML a lot (put id="alert" in HREF, tried to go with onclick). Tried with .alert, alert and #alert. tried to call the function before/after the jquery init, etc. etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put your custom code inside a `.js` file, upload it to your server, and reference it below the jQuery Core include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
```

and then inside the `custom.js` file you put your custom JS:

```
$(function () {
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    if ($alert.length) {
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 3000);
        $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
            $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

**Update**

I just noticed that your sample HTML has an element with the ID of `alert` and your JS code is searching for elements with the CLASS of `alert`. If you want to target an ID then you prepend a hash (`#`), not a period:

```
var $alert = $('.alert');
```

Should change to:

```
var $alert = $('#alert');
```

You will probably want to bone-up on jQuery selectors (it will save you a lot of time in the future): http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Mathieu This code finds the DOM elements it affects by itself, so all you have to do is include the `custom.js` file and it will all work. `var $alert = $('.alert');` gets the DOM element(s), `$alert.trigger('click');` triggers a click event on the found DOM element(s), etc...

Comment: @Mathieu It is important to note where on your server you upload the `custom.js` file and where on your server the current document is located. It's normally easiest to use an absolute URL to the `custom.js` file like: `src="/library/js/custom.js"` so it will work on every page you put it in no matter where on the site the document is located.

Comment: So somehow I must miss something because it doesn't work! I'll try from a new blank project to see what may go wrong.

Comment: @Mathieu Debug the `custom.js` file by putting `console.log()`s or `alert()`s in the code and see how far it runs. For instance put an `alert()` after `var $alert = $('.alert');`, then put one after: `if ($alert.length) {`, then put one... everywhere you think there might be a problem. When the `alert`s stop that's where the issue is in your code.

Comment: @Mathieu OK, I just looked at your sample code again and you are using an element with the ID of `alert` and the selector in your code is looking for elements with the class of `alert`. Change `var $alert = $('.alert');` to `var $alert = $('#alert');` and your code should work. Also you should check-out the list of jQuery selectors:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: But I'm on localhost for the moment, that shouldn't be a problem, or could it?

Comment: Thanks! I will read carefull your link. I've tried to put alert("test") in many places in the .js file and it didn't work. So I guess for some unclear reason the file is not found (even though it says the link is fine in my html code)

Comment: @Mathieu If you are testing on your local computer and have not setup a web server (like IIS) then you can't absolutely reference the `custom.js` file; if this is the case then it's a good idea to use relative URLs.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

It would look exactly the same except in a separate file. Let's say the file is added in a subfolder of `documentroot` `/js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/site.js"></script>
```

site.js

```
$(function () {
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    if ($alert.length) {
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 3000);
        $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
            $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks good you can do this

**Html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="YourScript.js"></script>
```

**Content of YourScript.js**

```
$(function () {
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    if ($alert.length) {
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 3000);
        $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
            $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the suggest solutions I just wanna add on more suggestion that help DRY things up a little, try using an HtmlHelper extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString JsScript(this HtmlHelper helper, string jsFileName)
{
  TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("script");
  builder.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript");
  builder.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
  builder.Attributes.Add("src", "Scripts/" + jsFileName);
  return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

This way if you decided you wanna move your scripts to a different folder all you have to do is update your extension method, plus it looks nice in the view:

```
@Html.JsScript("MyViewScript.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at various blogs and articles about "[Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)":

- http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/
- http://www.webstandards.org/action/dstf/manifesto/
- http://icant.co.uk/articles/seven-rules-of-unobtrusive-javascript/